# Compiling From Source vs. Pre-compiled Windows Binaries

Tags: php

So in the past I've always used the pre-compiled [Windows PHP binaries](http://windows.php.net/download/) but then [this guide](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) caught my attention.

That brings me to this:

- Why would someone want to compile PHP from the sources when the binaries are available for them?
- Is there a performance bonus I should be aware of?
- If so, is it a significant enough amount that I should take notice?

For reference, I use PHP for mostly CLI applications mainly for bulk data processing and some website info collection.
My system specs: Windows 7 x64, 6gb RAM, Intel Q6600 (2.4gHz x 4).

Comment: 1. so they can read\edit it first, 2. no unless you change it, 3.no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three good reasons I can think of for compiling PHP rather than using a binary build on Windows:

- you need a compiled in extension or compile-time-option that does not come as standard with available binaries
- you are short of memory and need a leaner PHP executable devoid of extensions you do not use
- you want a binary compiled specifically for your processor/environment to gain the small performance boost this might achieve (possible if you have an unusual setup)

Otherwise, just stick with the binary.

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the provider of the binaries that they aren't doing something evil, then I don't see how the performance would be significantly different from anything you could compile, unless your compiler is significantly better than the norm.

---

As Dagon indicated, really paranoid (or once-bitten) sysadmins would rather compile from source.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would someone want to compile PHP
>   from the sources when the binaries are
>   available for them?

I suppose one reason would be to enable the specific extensions one needs -- possibly compiling them statically, instead of using external .dll files

Another reason *(mostly on Linux, though)* would be to have the latest version of PHP -- which is generally not the one provided by distributions.

> Is there a performance bonus I should
>   be aware of?

I suppose that, if you have some specific architecture on your server, the binary generated by a generic compilation could be less efficient than one generated specifically for it -- provided you used the right configuration options and switches to compile.

Also, if you compile (only) the extensions you need as embedded into the resulting binary, that's a couple of files you won't need to load dynamically.

> is it a significant enough amount that
>   I should take notice?

Considering you are not running some heavy-loaded website with hundreds of requests per second... not sure that compiling yourself would be that interesting...

*Especially considering that compiling PHP on Windows is a bit harder than on Linux...*